# Submit Button doesn't submit in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc, submit-button

Submit button doesn't submit out of a sudden in ASP.NET MVC when creating a new user when it worked previously. It did not show any invalid input or valid input. I'm not sure where the problem went wrong. Any suggestion would be helpful.This problem has been happening twice and the solution that I have done so far is recreating a new project which I think is not practical.

Here is my code to review.

Admincontroller.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateUser(Users usr)
    {
        // TODO: L09 Task 5 - Write secure code to insert TravelUser into database
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid Input";
            ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
            return View("CreateUser");
        }
        else
        {
            string insert = @"INSERT INTO WBUsers(UserId, UserPw,FullName, Email, UserRole,Dob,ContactNo,usr.Billing_Address)
            VALUES('{0}', HASHBYTES('SHA1','{1}'),'{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}',{6},'{7}')";

            // TODO: L10 Task 2a - Provide the SQL statement to reset member"
            if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(insert, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw, usr.FullName, usr.Email, usr.UserRole, usr.Dob, usr.ContactNo, usr.Billing_Address) == 1)
            {
                string template = @"Hi {0},<br/><br/>
                          Welcome to Ecommerce!
                           Your userid is <b>{1}</b> and password is <b>{2}</b>. Please change your password upon login.
                           <br/><br/>Adminstrator";
                string title = "Account Sign Up";
                string message = String.Format(template, usr.FullName, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw);
                string result = "";

                bool outcome = false;
                // TODO: L10 Task 2b - Call EmailUtl.SendEmail to send email
                //                     Uncomment the following line with you are done
                outcome = EmailUtl.SendEmail(usr.Email, title, message, out result);
                if (outcome)
                {
                    ViewData["Message"] = "Account Has Been Created";
                    ViewData["MsgType"] = "success";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Message"] = result;
                    ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = DBUtl.DB_Message;
                ViewData["MsgType"] = "danger";
            }
            return View("CreateUser");
        }
    }
```

CreateUser.cshtml

@model SignUp2.Models.Users;

```
<link href="~/lib/dtpicker/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/dtpicker/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // DateA
        $('#JSDateA')
            .datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' });
    });
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/styles/createform.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
        <form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CreateUser" method="post">
            <h3>Registration Form</h3>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="UserId">Username:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input asp-for="UserId" placeholder="User ID" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="FullName">Full Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input asp-for="FullName" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="Email">Email:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input asp-for="Email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="UserPw">Password:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input asp-for="UserPw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserPw" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="Dob">Birth Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input asp-for="Dob" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                           class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
                </div>
                
                <span asp-validation-for="Dob" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="ContactNo">Contact Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input asp-for="ContactNo" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span asp-validation-for="ContactNo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="Billing_Address">Billing Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span>    </label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input asp-for="Billing_Address" class="form-control" placeholder="Billing Address" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Billing_Address" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">User Role:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rb1"
                               asp-for="UserRole" value="user" checked />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="rb1">User</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rb2"
                               asp-for="UserRole" value="admin" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="rb2">Admin</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>

            @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
            {
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="alert alert-@ViewData["MsgType"]">
                            @Html.Raw(ViewData["Message"])
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The View markup looks okay. Did you check Developer Console? Also Did you try to debug the code? Set a breakpoint where `CreateUser` starts and check what result are you getting.

Comment: The form CreateUser is not submitting anything. Could the layout contribute to this problem?

Comment: No layout just handles the UI part. It doesn't handle submission. I can see that your view doesn't have model binding. That might be an issue. At the top of the View page you must write `@model YourProjectName.Models.TableName` where YourProjectName is the name of your Project, Models is name of the folder `Models` and TableName is the name of table in which you are performing the action. It could be ViewModel also.

Comment: To learn more about Model Binding you can refer this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_model_binding.htm#:~:text=ASP.NET%20MVC%20model%20binding%20allows%20you%20to%20map,sent%20by%20the%20browser%20in%20an%20HTTP%20request.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your date picker, the validation label is not correctly set ( it set for contact no) and I recommended you to put your script after your HTML code

Comment: @noobprogrammer yup i have the added the model binding in my view. the same problem persists. Could any  other things contribute to the problem? for example the datepicker?

Comment: Press f12 in your browser, check if there is any error in the Console tab.

Comment: Is what you included for CreateUser.cshtml exactly what is in the file? Is so, that markup is not valid.